# Error en algunos casos

Tags: javascript

Estoy escribiendo este código para ordenar alfabéticamente, pero si le paso un String con dos palabras que inicien con la misma letra y estén consecutivas; me da el siguiente error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Este es el String de ejemplo, en el cual hay dos palabras iniciando con "p" juntas; ahí es donde falla ya que si quitamos, por ejemplo "probar"

```
const pPrueba = "hola ordename de manera alfebatica teniendo varias coincidencias alteradas para probar el codigo";
```

De este modo si funciona

```
const pPrueba = "hola ordename de manera alfebatica teniendo varias coincidencias alteradas para el codigo";
```

```js
const alfa = [
  "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
  "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
  "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ",
  "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
  "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
];

//puede editar este string
const pPrueba = "hola ordename de manera alfebatica teniendo varias coincidencias alteradas para probar el algoritmo";

const hazArr = (palabras) => {
  let arrCreado = palabras.split(" ");

  return arrCreado;
};

const borraItem = (arR, item) => {
  let i = arR.indexOf(item);

  i !== -1 && arR.splice(i, 1);
};

//array devuelto con la variable hazArr
const arrPalabras = hazArr(pPrueba);
//console.log(arrPalabras);

let letra = 0, letraAlfa = 0, pabsLetra = 0;

let pabsRe = [];

//verifica letra y añade palabra a pabsRe
function verif(arr) {
  arr.forEach(pabs => {
    if(pabs[letra] == alfa[letraAlfa]) {
      pabsRe.push(pabs);
      borraItem(arr, pabs);
    }
  });

  if(!arr.includes([][letra] == alfa[letraAlfa])) {
    letraAlfa++;
  }

  while(arr.length > 0) {
    verif(arr);
  }
  
  return pabsRe;
}

const verifArr = verif(arrPalabras);
console.log(letraAlfa);
console.log(verifArr);
console.log(arrPalabras);
```

Comment: Los ciclos while resultan ser peligrosos en ciertos casos donde el programador se confunde en la logica o realiza una operacion logica incorrecta que termina en un bucle infinito, ese error se debe a que javascript ha alcanzado el maximo de llamadas posibles en una pila y no las puede ejecutar, así que para forsozamente el bucle, para solucionarlo hay que mirar en que condición lógica te haz equivocado o que variables permiten que el bucle sea infinito.

Comment: Por ejemplo, una de las posibles fallas es que posiblemente no estes eliminando nunca objetos en el array enrealidad, haciendo que la condicion siempre se cumpla.

Comment: ¿Por qué no ocupas sort?

Comment: Pudiendo simplificar todo lo que haces en una sola línea ocupando esto: `const pPrueba = "hola ordename de manera alfebatica teniendo varias coincidencias alteradas para probar el algoritmo"; console.log(pPrueba.split(" ").sort());`

Comment: @FernandoTorres tengo otro archivo en el que ya lo hice con sort

Comment: @Riven gracias, lo checaré

Comment: Alguna razón en especial para no utilizar [Array.sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)?
Puedes tomar el mismo arreglo que haces separando las palabras por el espacio en blanco y utilizar el método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es efectivamente que el *array* `arr` nunca acaba de limpiarse. No se eliminan todos los elementos en él. Por lo que el `while(arr.length > 0)` es inifinito.

El problema ocurre cuando hay dos palabras consecutivas que empiezan por la misma letra. Como tú anotabas, podría ser el caso de `... para probar ...`.
Y ocurre en el `forEach`.

La función `splice` no es una función pura. Es decir, modifica el *array* directamente.
Cuando en el mismo `forEach` necesitas eliminar dos palabras (el caso de dos palabras consecutivas que empiezan por la misma letra), una vez eliminas la primera, el siguiente elemento del `forEach` no es el elemento siguiente del *array*, sino el d dos posiciones más adelante.
Te pongo un ejemplo.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.forEach((val, index) => {
    console.log(`Elemento ${val} en posición ${index}`);
    if (val === 3) {
        borraItem(arr, val);
    }
});
// Elemento 1 en posición 0
// Elemento 2 en posición 1
// Elemento 3 en posición 2
// Elemento 5 en posición 3
```

Fíjate como ya no muestra el elemento `4`. Porque en el *array* original, `4` está en la cuarta posición (index 3). Cuando eliminamos el elemento `3`, el `4` está en la segunda posición (index 2) pero la acabamos de recorrer; por lo que el siguiente elemento de la iteración será el `5`, en el índice 2+1.

De modo que, para solucionar el caso de las dos palabras consecutivas, debemos iterar con un `for` a mano y, en caso de eliminar un elemento, decrementar el valor del índice para ir efectivamente al siguiente elemento.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    const pabs = arr[i];

    if(pabs[letra] == alfa[letraAlfa]) {
        pabsRe.push(pabs);
        borraItem(arr, pabs);

        // Si borramos, decrementamos i
        --i;
    }
}
```

De este modo solventamos las palabras consecutivas.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: si me sirvió hermano, muchas gracias